# How to put a text at the end of the last sentence of a document with xelatex?

Tags: macros, xetex, text-manipulation

I have a lot of documents witch all have to share the same last text.

But this text have to follow the last sentence immediately — without line break —.

I try to modify the `document` environment but it doesn’t work because I have a line-break.

So, this is an example of the code I want to compile with xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\thelasttext{\textbf{(this the last text)}}

\begin{document}

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse
ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna.
Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at,
tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy
pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa
ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Mae-
cenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum.
Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia
nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim.
Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cur-
sus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum
pellentesque felis eu massa.
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus
tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In
hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis.
Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed
gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim.
Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae 

\end{document}
```

And this is the rendering I expect:[image]

As you see, I wonder the text I set on `\thelasttext` variable follow immediately and in the same line the last sentence. That’s why the redefinition of `document` environment isn’t exactly the solution.

So, is it possible to that with xelatex? and how?

Edit: Expliciting the need of xelatex.

Comment: If you can live with no white space between the last sentence and `\end{document}`, then `\AtEndDocument{\textbf{(this the last text)}}` in the preamble should do it.

Comment: Yes… but that’s exactly the point, I can’t every-time be sure that no white space will be between the last sentence and `\end{document}`.

Comment: This discussion may help (to clarify, not to solve) : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311991/latex-avoid-new-paragraph]

Comment: the previous paragraph has already been broken into lines if you have  blank line before the end, adding additional text would change the linebreaking of the whole paragraph, there is no way to do this in TeX.

Comment: So, @DavidCarlisle there is no way to del the suppress the last broken lines? A command like `\delprevious` witch I’ll can put before `\end{document}`, by modifying the `document` environment?

Comment: i developed a solution using \everypar, but it REQUIRED a blank line at the end.  You want something that works both ways.

Comment: Hmm… not exactly, I can be sure that all project will have a blank line at the end. But I cant be sure that all project will not have blank line, so @JohnKormylo probably your solution could be helpful.

Comment: Not if full generality no, you need to catch the paragraph before it starts, so you can add text before linebreaking,  and as you don't know which paragrap is last until the end you would have to trap/test _every_ paragraph. that will be massively invasive for the whole document and be bound to break something, except for the simplest of documents.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But in displaymaths there's a primitive length (don't remember the name) that gets checked to see if it inserts math “shortskips”. One could remove the lastskip, remove one baselineskip and add a box with that width, and it would look similar. Is that possible?

Comment: @Manuel you can use display math to measure the last line of a paragraph in restricted cases, but you can't reflow the paragraph to add the text (which might not fit) and you can't do anything if a page break has already shipped out the last paragraph

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought of faking it by removing the space from last line. That, together with an active definition of `\par` might work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to experiment with this:

```
\newwrite\tmpfile  \newcount\numpar  \newcount\numpars

\openin10=\jobname.num
\ifeof10 \numpars=-1 \else \closein10 \numpars=\input\jobname.num \relax \fi
\immediate\openout\tmpfile=\jobname.num

\def\thelasttext{{\bf (The last blaf.)}}

\def\par{\ifhmode 
     \global\advance\numpar by1 
     \ifnum\numpar=\numpars \thelasttext \fi 
     \endgraf 
  \fi
}
\def\bye{\par \immediate\write\tmpfile{\the\numpar}\penalty0\end}

First paragraph. Ruerrhv lnss ks.

Second. Mfffkl kjd s sf.

Last. Nsf sjkvf jkf fffbfd.

\bye
```

The external file `\jobname.num` is used. The number of paragraphs in the document is saved here. Of course, you must to process the document twice if you need to see the effect.

The `\bye` macro (or `\end{document}` in your case, where `\AtEndDocument` is declared as `\par\immediate\write\tmpfile{\the\numpar}`) can have empty line immediately before it but this is not explicitly needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that might work if the document is simple, and if packages and kernel does the right job when saving/restoring the definition of `\par`. Which is not probable.

```
\def\thelasttext{\textbf{(this the last text)}}
\let\savedpar\par
\protected\def\par{\futurelet\tmp\editedpar}
\protected\def\editedpar
  {\ifx\tmp\end\expandafter\editedparcheckend\else\expandafter\savedpar\fi}
\protected\def\editedparcheckend\end#1%
  {\def\tmpa{#1}\def\tmpb{document}\ifx\tmpa\tmpb
   \thelasttext\let\thelasttext\relax\fi\savedpar\end{#1}}
\AtEndDocument{\thelasttext}
```